# Could not get unknown property 'file'

Tags: android

I'm using Android Studio 2.2.2 and have ran into this problem:

> Could not get unknown property'file' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencies.DefaultDependencyHandle

I try to import `Airtube-android-api.jar` like this:

`dependencies{compile file'libs/Airtube-android-api.jar'}`

Answer (score 1):

That should be `compile file('libs/Airtube-android-api.jar')`